# How is charge limiting achieved in laptops? Why does it cause heating when limit is reached?

Tags: relay, heat, charge

Laptops have this feature which allow you to limit battery charging to up to a certain percentage.

Electronics wise, how is this charge limiting achieved? Is there actually a proper relay cutting off the charging path?

I have noticed that my laptop would start heating up significantly once the charge limit set has been reached. This makes me suspect that instead of having a proper relay to cut off charging, the electronics/software is just simply increasing power consumption to make it such that there is no net charging going on. If this is indeed the case, it is very bad behavior.

If there is indeed a relay in the circuit, which I presume would be solid state rather than proper electromagnetic coil relays, why is there so much heating once the limit is reached? I doubt the leakage current of the relay would be high enough to cause so much heat.

*I am not interested in is or how charge limiting is beneficial to battery life.*

Comment: not a relay, but an electronic switch (probably just a MOSFET).

Comment: Same thing in this context regardless. Also technically they are the same thing, just different ratings. There are solid state relays use MOSFETs for example.

Comment: no, that's not really the case, but anyways.

Answer (score 2):

There is no relay to cut anything.

When the charge controller has determined that the requested charge level has been achieved (could be 100%, could be 80, or whatever set to), the charge controller just stops charging the battery more.

Now you are fully operating on AC power only, and AC power is not used for charging, so the computer can use more of the power available from AC power adapter to run faster and do things quicker if necessary so it will obviously convert more power to heat in CPU and GPU. When battery is charging, the AC adapter must provide power to charge the battery and to run the laptop. If you turn off the laptop then all the available power can be used to charge the battery. So when laptop is on, the available power has to be split between running the laptop and charging the battery.

Comment: Commented on the last paragraph in Marcus's answer's reply. Re no relay and "just stops charging" I assume here you mean it is just a MOSFET or whatever simple switch doing the stopping.

Comment: there. is. no. stopping. to. do. Instead, it just does not *continue to charge*. It's like how I stop shoplifing simply by not doing shoplifting. There's nothing I need to "stop it". I just don't anymore. (not that I ever shoplifted, but it's the first active verb I could think of)

Comment: You were doing something before, you need to stop doing it to become not doing it anymore. This debate over choice of words is not productive.

Comment: Well, the charging is likely done by a buck regulator of some sorts, so the buck regulator is turned off, so the FETs don't switch any more and they don't pass current.

Comment: @everythingtrashthesedays The buck regulator that was driving current into the battery stops oscillating. Since the converter is off no current will flow.

Answer (score 0):

> his makes me suspect that instead of having a proper relay to cut off charging, the electronics/software is just simply increasing power consumption to make it such that there is no net charging going on.

That sounds like much much much more complicated, error prone, and expensive, than just relying on the charge controller that you need to have anyways with Lithium Batteries. So, no. That's certainly not what is happening.

> why is there so much heating once the limit is reached?

So, nobody knows exactly what is going on in your laptop. This might be as simple as "I notice this especially in situations where the battery gets completely charged, because these are those when the laptop is connected to an external power supply, and that's when it's unthrottled", it might be as stupid as a bug in some desktop software program that starts updating the "full battery" icon a couple thousand times per second, or it might be because the DC/DC supplies converting the external input voltage to the voltage rail needed by the actual laptop electronics is less efficient (produces more heat for the same load) than when working from battery voltage.

Comment: Indeed one would notice heating when the battery is fully charged. The question of how charging is stopped applies equally to that situation. Your software bug theory is interesting but I dont think such a bug even if they exist will cause so much resource usage to result in the significant heating observed. Heating due to being higher unthrottled performance mode cannot be the case, as it would have been unthrottled whilst charging as well, since the charger is plugged in. As for inefficiency, wouldnt it apply to external to battery charge as well? So that doesnt seem like the reason either.

Comment: "How is charging stopped": see Justme's answer. It's simply not done anymore. And, That bug story was not made up. A tray icon fully occupying 100% of a core has happened, more than once. The rest of your comments is answered with "no, it's how I wrote, that's possible.)

Comment: On second review of Justme's answer, I guess the "more unthrottled" idea is plausible explanation I suppose. With "more" being the keyword here. Would be interesting if someone were to test if there was actually higher performance at full charge and plugged in vs not full charge and plugged in. That would prove/disprove this theory.

Comment: you're literally the only person sitting in front of your laptop. Nobody owes proving anything to you ;)

Comment: Apologies if it was implied it only happens to my laptop. This is a common observation in newer laptops. I dont care enough to prove it, I am leaving a thought for anyone who may be interested.

Comment: It's not something I can observe, so I'll challenge your "common" a bit here :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have noticed that my laptop would start heating up significantly once the charge limit set has been reached.

Energy stored in the battery is energy that is not yet heat. During charging, perhaps half or more of the energy is transferred to the battery and thus not available as heat. Once charging stops, energy is no longer being stored and instead is available to become heat.